# Mail merge in gmail using secondary account

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am completely new to Google Apps Script and am attempting to complete what should be a fairly basic mail merge from gmail.  I have downloaded a script and template that works 99% correctly, however, it does not allow the user to adjust the email address or account that the emails come from.  I have several email accounts that are linked to my gmail account and this script only lets me send using my gmail domain account (myname@gmail.com).  Does anyone out there know how I could edit the below code to allow use of my alternative linked account (myname@domain.com)?  The code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  mySheet.addMenu('Mail Merge', [{name:'Send Emails', functionName:'sendEmail'}]);
}

function sendEmail() {

  //Get Sheet
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rowCount = mySheet.getLastRow();

  //Get Basic Email Data
  var emSubject = mySheet.getRange('K2').getValue();
  var emFromName = mySheet.getRange('K3').getValue();
  var emFrom = mySheet.getRange('K4').getValue();

  //Build Email Body
  var emBody = '';
  var textFound = false;
  for (var i=rowCount; i>=6; i--) {
    var line = mySheet.getRange('J' + i).getValue();
    if (line != '' || textFound) {
      emBody = line + '<br/>' + emBody;
      textFound = true;
    }
  }

  //Process Emails
  var remainingQuota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  remainingQuota = remainingQuota;

  var emailsSent = 0;

  for (var i=3; i<=rowCount; i++) {
    var emTo = mySheet.getRange('B' + i).getValue();
    if (emTo != '' && mySheet.getRange('A' + i).getValue() == '') {

      if (remainingQuota > 0) {

        //Add Merge Fields To Body
        var thisEmBody = emBody;
        thisEmBody = thisEmBody.replace(/\[GreetingName\]/g, mySheet.getRange('C' + i).getValue());
        thisEmBody = thisEmBody.replace(/\[DATA2\]/g, mySheet.getRange('D' + i).getValue());
        thisEmBody = thisEmBody.replace(/\[DATA3\]/g, mySheet.getRange('E' + i).getValue());
        thisEmBody = thisEmBody.replace(/\[DATA4\]/g, mySheet.getRange('F' + i).getValue());
        thisEmBody = thisEmBody.replace(/\[DATA5\]/g, mySheet.getRange('G' + i).getValue());
        thisEmBody = thisEmBody.replace(/\[DATA6\]/g, mySheet.getRange('H' + i).getValue());

        //Send Emails
        MailApp.sendEmail(emTo, emSubject, thisEmBody, { htmlBody:thisEmBody, name:emFromName, replyTo:emFrom })
        mySheet.getRange('A' + i).setValue('Sent');
        remainingQuota--;
        emailsSent++;

      } else {

        mySheet.getRange('A' + i).setValue('QUOTA EXCEEDED');

      }

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }

  Browser.msgBox(emailsSent + ' email' + ((emailsSent!=1)?'s':'') + ' sent.' + ((emailsSent==0) ? ' - Please make sure the status column (A) is empty and there are email addresses in column B' : ''))

}
```

I have looked around a bit but have not been able to identify a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instead use `GmailApp.sendEmail()` you can get that functionality. [See the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#sendEmail).

You just add a `from:"yourOtherEmail@domain.com"` to the advancedArgs.

You can query for what aliases are available to use by using [`GmailApp.getAliases()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#getAliases).

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question it is not clear wether your `@domain` is an alias of your `@gmail` account... if not, the rule is quite simple : the mails are sent using the script owner's account so the only thing you have to do is to create the script in your `@domain` account and the mails will automatically be sent from this account.